# rust - std::string::String as a byte string (i.e. b"foo" or deprecated bytes!("foo"))

Tags: rust

I see that

```
let s = String::from_str("hello");
let bytes = s.into_bytes();
assert_eq!(bytes, vec![104, 101, 108, 108, 111]);
```

but what i would like to do is have

```
assert_eq!(s.something(), b"hello");
```

where `.something()` is just a placeholder, it might be `something(s)` or similar.

I am doing this so i can use strings with

```
fn foo(mut stream: BufferedStream<TcpStream>, str: String) {
   stream.write(str.something());
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.something()` you want is called `.as_slice()`.  Generally the word for a `&[T]` in rust is a slice, and the naming convention to cheaply borrow a type as another (in this case, from a `Vec<T>`) is `.as_foo()`.  In this new comparison, you are comparing `&[u8]`, instead of allocating a new `Vec` to compare.  This should be much more efficient as well as more readable, since no allocation is needed.

```
    assert_eq!(bytes.as_slice(), b"hello");
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you better write this:

```
fn foo(mut stream: BufferedStream<TcpStream>, s: String) {
   stream.write(s.something());
}
```

as this:

```
fn foo(mut stream: BufferedStream<TcpStream>, s: &str) {
   stream.write(s.something());
}
```

As a rule of thumb, try to use slices (`&str` for `String`) first, and if it does not work because of ownership, use `String`.

Second, the method you're looking for is called [`as_bytes()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes):

```
fn foo(mut stream: BufferedStream<TcpStream>, s: &str) {
   stream.write(s.as_bytes());
}
```

There is no need to convert `String` to `Vec<u8>` first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the extra insight it gives. I +1 but as a personal rule I always accept the first correct answer. I would be interested to know what is the reasoning behind the rule of thumb. Thanks!

Comment: @Victory, it makes your functions more general. If you have a function which takes a reference (or a slice), you can work with it if you either own the data or also have a reference. Obtaining a reference/slice from owned data is very easy and essentially free. If the function takes a non-reference (e.g. `String` instead of `&str`), you can only pass owned piece of data to it. If you own the data, you pass your ownership to the function (which may be undesirable) or you clone the data (which is usually expensive and may be impossible). If you have a reference, you can *only* clone it.

Comment: Thank you again. I read your response and after searching found some confirmation of your rule of thumb. I think others will benefit from reading the link I found: http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-strings.html

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
  let bytes = vec![104, 101, 108, 108, 111];
  assert_eq!(String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()).unwrap(), "hello");
```